# Laravel where clause not returning expected result

Tags: php, laravel

While making a request to my Laravel database something goes wrong. I'm trying to get different recipes on user input but Postman is returning 'No recipes found'.
My Laravel controller code:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'search' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    // return response($request);

    $recipes = Recipe::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$request.'%')->get();

    if (count($recipes) > 0 ) {
        return response($recipes);
    } else {
        return response('No recipes found');
    }
}
```

if I return the response it returns `"search": "maken"` with the request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search?search=maken`.
When I however hardcode the where clause to `$recipes = Recipe::where('title', 'LIKE', 'maken')->get();` it returns some recipes and the search function works. Now I'm not sure whether the error is in my Postman request or in my search function in Laravel. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$request->INPUT_NAME` or `$request->input('name')` to get the value, so your code should be:

```php
$recipes = Recipe::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```php
$recipes = Recipe::where('title', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')->get();

if ($recipes->count() > 0 ) {
    return response($recipes);
} else {
    return response('No recipes found');
}
```